# JqueryUI dialog opening when called from console but not from js file with the same code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When using the autoOpen as false and initializing a jquery UI dialog, and then later on using dialog("open") and dialog("close"), I have not had problems in the past. For some reason in my latest project this seems to fail when called from code, but when called from the console manually, it works. (and it also works in firefox perfectly, fails in my other test environments though IE9 and Chrome). Any ideas on what to check? (so far I have tried comparing to my other projects, setting z-index, moving the div to other areas of the page, and different doctypes to no avail). I am using jquery 1.11.1, jqueryUI 1.10.4, and there are datatables.net controls on the page, but the dialog is NOT inside of this control. that lib is 1.9.4  so.. ANY suggestions would be helpful, thanks!

code that fires early on:

```
$("#csProgressPanel").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Progress",
            width: 316,
            height: 116,
            autoOpen: false,
            disabled: false,
            center: true,
            dialogClass: 'no-close'
        });
```

code that is called later on (just before mvc ajax requests - note, this code works from within the web console, just not when called from my js file for some reason):

```
$("#csProgressPanel").dialog("open");
```

code called much later:

```
$("#csProgressPanel").dialog("close");
```

UPDATE:

I am using this as a 'wait' dialog for my serverside calls, and it appears to open and close really fast AFTER the serverside call. Here is the code I am using:

```
function ShowWaitDialog() {
    $("#csProgressPanel").dialog("open");
}

function HideWaitDialog() {
    console.log("closing popup");
    $("#csProgressPanel").dialog("close");
}

function JSON_AjaxRequest(controller, method, parameters, callBackSuccess) {

    ShowWaitDialog();

    var savedData = "";

    if (!parameters || parameters.length < 1)
        parameters = "{}";
    else
        parameters = JSON.stringify(parameters);

    var hasError = false;
    var lastErrorMessage = "";

    $.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        url: SERVER_TO_USE + "/" + controller + "/" + method,
        data: parameters,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            callBackSuccess(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            hasError = true;
            lastErrorMessage = errorThrown;
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            HideWaitDialog();
            if (hasError) {
                var errorObject = ErrorHandling.BuildClientSideError(lastErrorMessage);
                ErrorHandling.ShowErrors(errorObject);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: If it works in the console but not from the JS file, then most likely it's not executing or your JS file has an error. Put some alert statements around the open and close statements to see if it even reaches that code.

Comment: Thanks that is a good idea, but I have followed it with debugger, console.log, and alerts and it is executing the code but the dialog does not display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the following line from the ajax call fixed the problem with the dialog.

```
async: false,
```

feel free to edit this answer if you can explain WHY this is the solution, but it surely works. I don't remember why I wanted it to be synchronous, hopefully it was not important :)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand you to put several console.log() statement within your code to see where your are going.

I would also remove for instance the "CLOSE" dialog as your window may just be opened and closed very fast.

Comment: After removing the close, the popup indeed shows. I don't understand why though because I make a serverside call AFTER the call (i am basicly using this as a wait dialog for serverside calls). This is definately getting me in the right direction. If i cant solve it shortly, then I will add my ajax call code to my question - perhaps the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe there's a timing issue, like jQuery is not finding the element or you're calling dialog("open") before there's anything to open.  I've had a similar issue where printing an element to the console shows me that the element is not null - but in fact it is!
 Sometimes a selection is a "live" selection, and will kind of update automatically, so it can be tough to tack down. I would check your timing and make sure that jQuery is really finding the right element at the right time.

Comment: Good idea, but I tried using setTimeout to no avail, also at a breakpoint I checked the length of the jquery selector and it is indeed finding the element. The initialization occurs from document.ready, and the open occurs off of button events.